# Spring Security: Not able to logout/invalidate session

Tags: spring, spring-security, logout

My spring security logout configuration:

```
<security:logout logout-success-url="/login.htm" invalidate-session="true"/>
```

And in my JSP, I have provided

<`a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>`

When I click on the 'Logout' button, it does re-direct to my login page. But when I try to go to my welcome page by giving the url, it allows me to. Only when I referesh the page again, it prompts me for the credentials

Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: When you say it allows you to go to the welcome page, is it actually taking you there or is it really showing a cached page?

Comment: I guess it is the cached page.. but how do we make sure that doesn't get displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as though you're able to see a cached welcome page once you've logged out.

To prevent the caching you can add an [interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/WebContentInterceptor.html) to your Spring dispatcher config which will set certain headers telling the browser not to cache. You can apply the interceptor to all `.htm` pages - or just a subset if you needed to. To apply to all `.htm` pages:

```
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**/*.htm" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in the head tag to disable the cache solved the problem for me

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
```